# activar un swich con un select

Tags: php, html

mi pregunta es como puedo activar este swich con la opción seleccionada por el select que se tiene arriba

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Reporte Indicadores</legend>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputState">Elija un indicador para hacer unreporte</label>
 <select id="Reporte" class="form-control" name="Reporte">
```

```
 <?php
                    $consulta = "SELECT
              k_indicadores.IdIndicador,
              k_indicadores.Descripcion
              FROM
              k_indicadores
                  ";
                    $resultado = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
                    echo '<option value="">Seleccione una opción</option>';
                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) {
                        $s = '';
                        if ($row['IdIndicador'] == $Interes) {
                            $s = 'selected="selected"';
                        }
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['IdIndicador'] . '" ' . $s . '>' . $row['Descripcion'] . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>   

if ($s) {
$obj->setIdIndicador($s);
$obj->getRegistro();

switch ($obj->getIdPresentacion()) {
    case 1:
        //unico
        $consulta = $obj->getQueryConsulta();
        $result = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consulta);
        //echo $consulta;
        echo '<br><center><table width="600px" height="150px" border="1" bordercolorlight="#999999" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr class="titulo_tabla" align="center"> 
    <td colspan="2" ><font size="10">' . $obj->getDescripcion() . '</font></td>
    </tr>';
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td class="contenido_tabla"><font size="7">' . $obj->getDescripcion() . '</font></td>';
            echo '<td class="contenido_tabla" align="center"><font size="7">' . $row['series'] . '</font></td>';
            echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table></center>';
        break;
```

Comment: Para eso tienes que utilizar ajax en donde captures el ID que el usuario selecciono lo pasa al PHP y hay haces el ciclo del switch

Comment: y como se hace en el mismo php o tendria que crear otro archivo